# Is there a way to generate sitemap on social network icons linking to the respective social network sites present on the the rails platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap-generator-gem

I am using **sitemap_generator** gem to generate sitemap for my rails application. I have generated sitemap for most of the part including youtube videos.

Now I added social icons like facebook, twitter, linkedin, and youtube in the footer with each of them linking to their respective social network profile. Like following

```
<div class="social">
     <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <a target="_blank" href="facebook_url"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
     <a target="_blank" href="twitter_url"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
     <a target="_blank" href="linkedin_url"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x social"></i></a>
     <a target="_blank" href="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
     <a target="_blank" href="youtube_url"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
</div>
```

How can I write a method in **sitemap.rb** file inorder to include these social media links in site map?

Answer (score 0):

You can add links manually:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add '/facebook_url'
  #etc.
end
```

You can specify a different host on a per link basis.

The documentation says it:

> **:default_host** - String. Required. Host including protocol to use when
>   building a link to add to your sitemap. For example
>   http://example.com. Calling add '/home' would then generate the URL
>   http://example.com/home and add that to the sitemap. You can pass a
>   :host option in your call to add to override this value on a per-link
>   basis. For example calling add '/home', :host => 'https://example.com'
>   would generate the URL https://example.com/home, for that link only.
>   For example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ccsdscsc

add '/ccsdscsc', :host => 'https://facebook.com'
```

ccsdscsc in this case would be the path to your facebook profile. You would do the same for your other social media links.

Comment: If I do this it will create a url like this `https://example.com/https://www.facebook.com/ccsdscsc` on the sitemap. This will be a invalid url

Comment: If you don't own the domain of the link you want to include in your Sitemap, you shouldn't add it. Sitemaps are meant for links that have your same domain name. All your user profiles, all posts, etc. You could redirect social links in your routes.rb but Google doesn't like that either. I suggest you don't add your social links to your sitemap.